# change this makefile so that it will automatically consider all files in a directory as a dependency?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

This is the first makefile I am making, I need you help to change it a little. 
Here is the makefile I have right now

```
VPATH = src
BUILD = build
BIN = bin
INCLUDE = C:\Users\sidhi\Desktop\Projects\sfml-snake\internalLibraries\include

$(shell mkdir -p build)
$(shell mkdir -p bin)

CC = g++ 
CFLAGS  = -g -std=c++11
LIBS=-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system


G++_VER_LT48 := $(shell expr `$(CC) -dumpversion | cut -f1-2 -d.` \< 4.8 )
ifeq ("$(G++_VER_LT48)","1")
$(error old version of g++ not supported, upgrade to 4.8 or higher)
endif


default: bin/game


$(BIN)/game: $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/game.o $(BUILD)/food.o $(BUILD)/snake.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/game $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/game.o $(BUILD)/food.o $(BUILD)/snake.o $(LIBS)


$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I $(INCLUDE)
```

I want to change it such that, all the files in the build/ directory gets added as a dependency. something like

```
bin/game: $(BUILD)/%.o
```

But that doesn't work.

Also, How can I include more path to the VPATH ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Make has a number of useful built-in functions you can use to generate lists of files. For example, this:

```
SRCFILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

creates a list of .cpp files in the current directory, and then this:

```
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
```

performs an edit on that list to create a new list of the corresponding .o files.

Comment: How to automatically create the directories within build/ directory ?

Comment: @SidhinThomas. If you have another question then post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like:

```
OBJ=$(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -type f -name "*.o")
```

And then:

```
$(BIN)/game: OBJ
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This doesn't work if you have not already generated the .o files - i.e. the first time you run the makefile.

Comment: I need it to do it automatically from the first time